# Word for the act of growing a limb back?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

So when a limb gets removed you are **dismembered**.

But some animals, like lizards, can grow limbs back.  E.g. if they lose a tail it can grow back.  Is there a word for this process?

A humorous word for it might be to be **remembered**.  I love the idea of a lizard *remembering its tail*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**regenerate**
verb
rɪˈdʒɛnəreɪt/
1.
(of a living organism) grow (new tissue) after loss or damage.
"the lizard has to find the wherewithal to regenerate its tail"

Not as fun as remembered though!

Comment: And **regrow** is also an accepted term for this ability. _"Some species of starfish have the ability to **regenerate** lost arms and can **regrow** an entire new limb given time"_